# RISC-V Arithmetic Shift vs Operator "<<<"

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I'm new at learning Verilog so some of my practices are based on already existing codes. I was reading the RISC-V implementation of arithmetic shift and didn't quite understand why it's that way when it can be a simple shift operator.

Since I'm a newbie at this topic I want to know if there's any practical difference between both implementations.

RISC-V Implementation snippet:

```
       //----------------------------------------------
       // Shift Left
       //----------------------------------------------   
       `ALU_SHIFTL :
       begin
            if (alu_b_i[0] == 1'b1)
                shift_left_1_r = {alu_a_i[30:0],1'b0};
            else
                shift_left_1_r = alu_a_i;

            if (alu_b_i[1] == 1'b1)
                shift_left_2_r = {shift_left_1_r[29:0],2'b00};
            else
                shift_left_2_r = shift_left_1_r;

            if (alu_b_i[2] == 1'b1)
                shift_left_4_r = {shift_left_2_r[27:0],4'b0000};
            else
                shift_left_4_r = shift_left_2_r;

            if (alu_b_i[3] == 1'b1)
                shift_left_8_r = {shift_left_4_r[23:0],8'b00000000};
            else
                shift_left_8_r = shift_left_4_r;

            if (alu_b_i[4] == 1'b1)
                result_r = {shift_left_8_r[15:0],16'b0000000000000000};
            else
                result_r = shift_left_8_r;
       end
```

Almost equivalent snippet:

```
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        data_out <= data_in <<< shift;
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RISC-V implementation explicitly creates a **barrel shifter**. A good Verilog compiler would create the same implementation from the `<<<` operator **if** that operator were used in a combinational procedural block. Since you didn't show us the entirety of the block I can't be sure about this. It's possible that this code could be part of a synchronous block, even though the code doesn't use non-blocking assignments, but I doubt it.

The code that you suggest is a synchronous block requiring that the shift be performed in a single cycle.